# Is there any difference between the words 'fusion' and 'melting '?

Tags: thermodynamics, terminology, phase-transition, fusion

My physics text says this:
'The change of state from **solid** to **liquid** is called **melting** and from **liquid** to **solid** is called **fusion**'.

But according to my chemistry text in a different context,
'The enthalpy change that accompanies the **melting** of one mol of a solid substance in standard state is called standard enthalpy of fusion'.

I think it is a pretty good assumption to say that fusion and melting are equivalent from this statement.

According to Wikipedia,

**Melting, or fusion** is a physical process that results in the phase transition of a substance from a solid to a liquid.

Why is this difference? All the  articles I have read so far define fusion as a transition from solid to liquid. So, why does my physics text say otherwise?

Also, in simple terms, fusion refers to the combination of things, right? So, won't it be more intuitive to say that fusion implies the transition to solid from liquid? (due to the formation of a more ordered structure).

I apologise if this was a silly question. But, I would still like to know the answers.

Comment: It seems there is a lot of conFUSION on the naming of the applicable latent heat. I wouldn't lose any sleep over it. The heat required to melt or solidify is the same except for the direction of heat flow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The English terminology on phase changes is imprecise from being mixed a lot with non-scientific daily usage.

- Solid $\to$ liquid: **Melting**
- Liquid $\to$ solid: **Freezing/fusion/solidification**

The ideal thermodynamic temperatures where these phase changes happen are the same, typically and interchangeably called *melting point*, *freezing point* or *ice point* (I've never heard *fusion point*, but why not). Also, the latent energies required for these phase changes are the same (with opposite signs), typically just called *latent heat of fusion*.

- Liquid $\to$ gas: **Evaporation/vaporization/boiling**
- Gas $\to$ liquid: **Condensation**

Here we typically talk about the *boiling point* or *steam point* as well as *latent heat of evaporation* for both. [Sometimes](https://sciencing.com/differences-between-vaporization-evaporation-12052824.html) *evaporation* refers specifically to a liquid-to-gas phase change below the boiling point, and *boiling*
only above the boiling point.

- Solid $\to$ gas: **Sublimation** *(rarely **evaporation**, often within materials science and microfabrication circles)*
- Gas $\to$ solid: **Deposition** *(rarely **condensation**, again sometimes in materials science and microfabrication contexts)*

These phase changes are uncommon in daily life outside the lab and don't have colloquial terms for phase-change temperatures. We would simply say *sublimation point* and *deposition point* when needed.

Comment: Merriam-webster gives this definition for *fusion* : "the act or process of liquefying or rendering plastic by heat", i.e. solid $\to$ liquid

Comment: @SolubleFish That is a different meaning - joining two solid materials by heating the interface between them so that they melt, and then allowing them to cool. This forms a strong bond between the materials if the liquids *dissolve* in each other.

Comment: So, if somebody  says that the magnitude of the latent heat for a particular reaction is X units, I won't be able to figure out what that reaction is, right? Dont these notations make the usage of these processes inconvenient and so how can their usage be justified?@Steeven. PS: I have heard of ice point and steam point as well

Comment: @Proxima Correct, if you just have the latent heat value for, say, fusion, then you can't know from that value whether we are dealing with melting or solidification. It is just an amount of energy. Nevertheless, it still does represent the energy needed for either of these processes, so the use of it as a property is definitely justified. It just doesn't convey or contain as much information as it could have. You are right that it is inconvenient with ambiguous terminology in certain fields - sometimes traditional use overcomes exactness and sense (queue, the old SI system...) Context is key.

Comment: @Proxima I have never heard the terms *ice point* and *steam point* before. Are they other terms for the freezing point and boiling point? I'm which context have you heard them?

Comment: Yes, they are(atleast, according to my text)The terms 'ice point' and 'steam point' are mentioned in a paragraph regarding the measurement of temperature using a thermometer .They have indicated 373.15 K as the steam point and 273.15 K as the ice point. 'Since all substances change dimensions with temperature, an absolute reference for expansion is not available (they are talking about measuring temperature using a thermometer ).The ice point and the steam point of water are two convenient fixed points and are known as the freezing and boiling points, respectively '

Comment: @Proxima Alright, I have added this to the answer. Thank you for the addition.

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard of fusion as a word for melting. Other answers made it sound like there was a fusion (combination) of heat in matter, but that is odd.
There is no "steam" point at 100*c (373.15k) because water vapor can exist below 0*C- Water condenses at DEW point that varies with relative humidity.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/361473)